# Can I remove the "round square" around an application icon on the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher

I want to make it look like the bottom dock of **Windows 7**. Is that possible? Maybe through the **Terminal**? I'm using **Bash** for the record. I'm using the **Unity** desktop.

[image: See the squares] Do you see the squares?

Comment: Could you be more specific? provide a screenshot, maybe?

Comment: @TreefrogInc I posted a picture in the post.

Comment: I'm currently trying to find a solution; for the meanwhile, try adjusting some settings through ccsm.

Comment: @TreefrogInc Did you find anything? I could not find anything on the CCSM.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll have to change the source code and re-build it, as this kind of configurability isn't built in. It's probably hard-coded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have found a solution that might work, if you wanted to make your desktop more like Windows 7 (as always, make a backup of everything, and be sure you know how to revert the changes you made, just in case):

**To move the Unity Launcher to the bottom of the screen**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paullo612/unityshell-rotated
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unityshell-rotated libnux-1.0-0 compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then enable **Ubuntu Unity Plugin Rotated** and disable **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** in ccsm.

**To remove the square backlight**

Next, open the new plugin, go to "experimental", and set the `launcher opacity` to 0. 
Find the `backlight mode` option and set it to `always off`.

If it still doesn't look the way you want it to, follow the rest of the instructions from [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-customise-unity-like-never-before/) and see how that turns out.

Comment: Thank you for finding the correct answer. You have done well.